# Is it possible to show any image on top of bar when user hover any bar in Amcharts

Tags: javascript, html, charts, amcharts, amcharts4

I am working on amcharts and my requirement is to show an image and top of the image its value when user hover any column is it possible in amcharts using version 4 ?

```js
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 * 
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 * 
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "country": "USA",
  "visits": 2025
}, {
  "country": "China",
  "visits": 1882
}, {
  "country": "Japan",
  "visits": 1809
}, {
  "country": "Germany",
  "visits": 1322
}, {
  "country": "UK",
  "visits": 1122
}, {
  "country": "France",
  "visits": 1114
}, {
  "country": "India",
  "visits": 984
}, {
  "country": "Spain",
  "visits": 711
}, {
  "country": "Netherlands",
  "visits": 665
}, {
  "country": "Russia",
  "visits": 580
}, {
  "country": "South Korea",
  "visits": 443
}, {
  "country": "Canada",
  "visits": 441
}, {
  "country": "Brazil",
  "visits": 395
}];

// Create axes

var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "country";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;

categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("dy", function(dy, target) {
  if (target.dataItem && target.dataItem.index & 2 == 2) {
    return dy + 25;
  }
  return dy;
});

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "visits";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
series.name = "Visits";
series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{categoryX}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
series.columns.template.fillOpacity = .8;

var columnTemplate = series.columns.template;
columnTemplate.strokeWidth = 2;
columnTemplate.strokeOpacity = 1;
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

As we can see when we hover any column it shows me a tooltip , but I want to show the image on top and its value on top of image when user hover any column , see the attached image .
[image: Required functionality]

There is an example of images on top of chart but i need to show image when its hover

https://www.amcharts.com/demos-v4/column-chart-images-top-v4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. You need this extra configuration, especially `tooltipHTML`:

```js
series.columns.template.tooltipHTML = '<div class="tooltip"><div><strong>{valueY}</strong></div><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/26/19/47/penguin-42936_960_720.png" alt="Linux"></div>';
series.columns.template.tooltipY = am4core.percent(0);
series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
series.tooltip.fontSize = 10;
series.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
series.tooltip.label.fill = "#000000";
series.tooltip.background.fill = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)";
series.tooltip.background.stroke = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)";
series.tooltip.background.filters.clear();
```

```css
.tooltip {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.tooltip img {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

**Warning** from the documentation: [Text versus HTML](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/tooltips/#Text_versus_HTML)

> HTML tooltips are not supported by older Internet Explorer browsers. Such tooltips will also not export to images when exporting your chart.

> It's important to know that if both `tooltipText` and `tooltipHTML` are set, the latter will take precedence on browsers that support it, falling back to the former on older browsers. Setting both might be a good strategy if you want to universally support all browsers.

If I put the above code in your example, we get the following result:

```js
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 * 
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 * 
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "country": "USA",
  "visits": 2025
}, {
  "country": "China",
  "visits": 1882
}, {
  "country": "Japan",
  "visits": 1809
}, {
  "country": "Germany",
  "visits": 1322
}, {
  "country": "UK",
  "visits": 1122
}, {
  "country": "France",
  "visits": 1114
}, {
  "country": "India",
  "visits": 984
}, {
  "country": "Spain",
  "visits": 711
}, {
  "country": "Netherlands",
  "visits": 665
}, {
  "country": "Russia",
  "visits": 580
}, {
  "country": "South Korea",
  "visits": 443
}, {
  "country": "Canada",
  "visits": 441
}, {
  "country": "Brazil",
  "visits": 395
}];

// Create axes

var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "country";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;

categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("dy", function(dy, target) {
  if (target.dataItem && target.dataItem.index & 2 == 2) {
    return dy + 25;
  }
  return dy;
});

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "visits";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
series.name = "Visits";
series.columns.template.fillOpacity = .8;
series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{categoryX}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
// ==================================================
series.columns.template.tooltipHTML = '<div class="tooltip"><div><strong>{valueY}</strong></div><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/26/19/47/penguin-42936_960_720.png" alt="Linux"></div>';
series.columns.template.tooltipY = am4core.percent(0);
series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
series.tooltip.fontSize = 10;
series.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
series.tooltip.label.fill = "#000000";
series.tooltip.background.fill = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)";
series.tooltip.background.stroke = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)";
series.tooltip.background.filters.clear();
// ==================================================

var columnTemplate = series.columns.template;
columnTemplate.strokeWidth = 2;
columnTemplate.strokeOpacity = 1;
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.tooltip {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.tooltip img {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```